# Add predefined function to onclick with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a little confusing. I'm creating this slider thing. When a slide is displayed, its onclick == "", and if it is hidden, onclick == "slide(#)" where # is the number of the slide. When you select a number to slide to, the current slide slides out, and the next slide comes in. During that, the onclick for the slide going out is suppose to == "slide(#)", and the onclick for the slide coming in is suppose to == "". My problem is reattaching the slide() to the onclick for the slide going out.

Here is my code so you can see everything that is going on: http://chigstuff.com/header/

Hopefully you can understand what I'm talking about. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to remove a click event from an element, use the unbind() function, not attr().  You getting any errors?

Comment: That is some pretty nasty code man. The best thing you could do is look through one of the jquery plugins that do this sort of thing. Here is one that is written very well. http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the [`.click([function])`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method instead of `.attr()` to assign the listeners.

Comment: `.live('click', slide(#))` is probably a better alternative.